# Avoid two time argument definition when passing function as argument typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

As far as I researched, if you want a function to be passed as an argument and used as a callback, you need to introduce in the method all the arguments that the callback function is going to use, and then once again for those same arguments, when you define the type of callback function in the arguments, so twice.

In my code example below, arguments between two asterisks have to be defined twice, because most of the arguments are for the callback function, of whom types have to be once again defined when you define the callback itself (see the last argument callbackFunc):

```
keyBoardListenerSet: (**gl:WebGLRenderingContext**, 
    document:Document, **primitiveType: GLenum**,
    **offset: number**, **count: number**, **program:WebGLProgram**,
    pos: Float32Array, rot: Float32Array, anglesChanged: {x:boolean, y:boolean, z:boolean},
    callbackFunc: (gl:WebGLRenderingContext, primitiveType: GLenum, offset: number,
    count: number, program: WebGLProgram) => void): void => {
    

    //really meaningful code


}
```

I was trying to pass the function with the arguments already set in a variable, and delay execution in my function to avoid argument type definition, but I think that is not possible (I'm new to Javascript), so if this is not possible, is there any less verbose way to use callback functions as arguments in typescript (by this I mean, a way to avoid set the type twice for the same argument that will be used in the callback function)? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refactor the type out into its own type declaration, and then you can also group the re-usable parameters into a single argument as an object:

e.g.

```
// could also be a Tuple if you don't want to type out param keys e.g. type A = [number, string]
type KeyboardListenerParam = {
    gl: WebGLRenderingContext,
    primitiveType: GLenum,
    offset: number,
    count: number,
    program: WebGLProgram,
    pos: Float32Array,
    rot: Float32Array,
    document: Document,
    anglesChanged: { x: boolean, y: boolean, z: boolean }
};

const something = {
    keyBoardListenerSet: (
        params: KeyboardListenerParam,
        callbackFunc: (params: KeyboardListenerParam) => void
    ): void => {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            callbackFunc(params);
        });
        //really meaningful code
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was what I was looking for. A new problem arises though, when I try to set directly the program userInput.keyBoardListenerSet({ gl, primitiveType, offset, count, shader.program, pos, rot, anglesChanged, document }, draw); I get an error in shader.program: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'shader' does not exist in type 'KeyboardListenerParam'.ts(2345). Cant I insert another classes property directly as an argument on the object passed as argument? (shader is separted class with the program as a property, const shader: Shader = new Shader(....)). Thanks

Comment: hmm, there's not a great way to avoid copying/passing the parameters explicitly unless you are using `e.g. _.pick` from lodash, I would probably just pass a fresh object and access the keys from `params` again.

Comment: you can pass all the object and the access the specific argument but also you can specity the name of the argument in the call, and that does the job. For example `keyBoardListenerSet({ gl, primitiveType, offset, count, program: shader.program }, pos, rot, anglesChanged, document, draw);` See the "program: shader.program"